# FBJS, FBML, and Dialogs

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs

Okay since I have little experience with this stuff and the Facebook documentation is very scattered, I figured I would ask StackOverflow.

I am making an iFrame Canvas Facebook application using FBJS and some PHP. I would like to make a Dialog box that displays a form for the user to enter some information to then be sent on to a database. I know how to program a good chunk of it but the main problem arises in just getting the dialog WITH the form up on the page. What would be the best way of doing so?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been developing Facebook apps since almost the beginning, and yes, the current documentation is very scattered! First, you should be using FBJS in an iframe app. FBJS was designed for use in FBML apps (non-iframe based). The only place you have to use it is in a Page tab. Unless you mean the Facebook javascript API.

You didn't mention what dialog you were trying to create. Here is a link to Facebook's "dialogs". http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

But I don't think that is what you are looking for. If you are trying to post to someone's wall, then this is the link you want. Scroll down to the "Dialog" section. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

But if you are just trying to prompt for information and save it, you can use plain javascript and html. You can even use libs like jquery, prototype, etc.

Comment: I think I'll take the jquery route with all of this instead of messing with Facebook's api's. Thanks for the help!